# Does a C++ shell framework exist?

Tags: c++, shell, command-line-interface, tui

I used to develop some Perl programs using [Fry::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/~bozo/Fry-Shell/). I think it is very powerful and easy to use.

For one of my C++ projects I need to create a command line client. The idea is to create a TUI like the one found in routing hardware.

Does such a framework exist ?

Comment: GNU readline or ncurses?

Comment: Hmm I did not thought of ncurse. My program is a kind of RPC client (using Thrift). I could make a "simple" GNU readline interface and an advanced one with ncurse...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ wrappers for ncurses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544280/c-wrappers-for-ncurses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using Fry::Shell. It's not much of a hassle to call Perl from C++. [Here's](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) a starting point for that, there might be a better way to do it.

EDIT: I just found a [project](https://github.com/dparrish/libcli) on Github. It's written in C and seems pretty much dead, but try it out, it might be useful. Even if it's not, since it's open source, you can use it as a starting point. It claims to provide a Cisco-like interface, which should suit you pretty well.

Comment: You mean calling Perl from C++, or using Perlembed?

Comment: Either, really.  I would hope that there's a native library for this sort of thing, rather than having to embed/call-out to Perl.  I'm not saying that this is a bad answer, though.

Comment: I have already developed a piece of code but I think that would be less painful using a framework.

Comment: It would not be difficult to use Perl instead but on the other hand mono-language projects are more homogeneous. Aren't they?